# LINQ2SQL select rows based on large where

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql, query-optimization

I'm searching for a bunch of int32's in a SQL (Compact edition) database using LINQ2SQL.

My main problem is that I have a large list (thousands) of int32 and I want all records in the DB where id field in DB matches any of my int32's. Currently I'm selecting one row at the time, effectively searching the index thousands of times.

How can I optimize this? Temp table?

Comment: Show us the LINQ query you are currently using.

Comment: Where do you get this list of int32 from?

Comment: I get the list of int32's from a complex and top secret thing. Does it matter? ;) It's the output of an algorithm looking for certain key points in pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert your ints in a SQL table then do :

```
var items = from row in table
            join intRow in intTable on row.TheIntColumn equals intRow.IntColumn
            select row;
```

**Edit 1 & 2:** Changed the answer so he joins 2 tables, no collections.

Comment: You cant join with a list in Linq2Sql

Comment: Well, then I'll edit my answer again to say he must do the thing I wrote in my edit already if he wants to use this solution ;-)

Comment: Tried other tips on this page. This one was the fastest by far.

Comment: You should look into 'LinqPad'. One of the feature I like most about the program is that you can see the resulting SQL query. This way, you can tweak your code a bit to let the 'Over-the-top'ly optimized SQL servers handle the load.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you could use a Contains query:

```
int[] intArray = ...;
var matches = from item in context.SomeTable 
              where intArray.Contains(item.id) 
              select item;
```

Comment: This won't work for many more than 2000 values - you get a serious error in the SQl logs.

Comment: Don't have SQL to hand, but somthing to do with executing a query with more than a certain number of parameters.

Comment: By the power of Google: http://bit.ly/mgahHX, and a SO question around this: http://bit.ly/j68myx

Comment: Interesting, I wasn't aware of this limitation

Comment: @ck would the same limitation occur if one build a dynamic where statement of OR expressions?

Answer (score 1):

For serarching for thousands of values, your options are:

- Send an XML block to a stored procedure (complex, but doable)
- Create a temp table, bulk upload the data, then join onto it (can cause problems with concurrency)
- Execute multiple queries (i.e. break your group of IDs into chunks of a thousand or so and use BrokenGlass's solution)

I'm not sure which you can do with Compact Edition.

Answer (score 0):

My Preference would be to writing a Stored Procedure for the search.  If you have an Index on the field that you are searching, It would make life a lot easier for you in the future when the amount of rows to process increases.

The complexity you will come across is writing a select statement that can do an IN Clause from an input parameter.  What you need is to have a Table-Valued function to convert the string (of Id's) into a Column and use that column in the IN Clause.
like:

```
Select *
From SomeTable So
Where So.ID In (Select Column1 From dbo.StringToTable(InputIds))
```

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with this linq solution after being tired of writing manual batching code.
It's not perfect (i.e. the batches are not exactly perfect) but it solves the problem.
Very useful when you are not allowed to write stored procs or sql  functions. Works with almost every linq expression.

Enjoy:

```
    public static IQueryable<TResultElement> RunQueryWithBatching<TBatchElement, TResultElement>(this IList<TBatchElement> listToBatch, int batchSize, Func<List<TBatchElement>, IQueryable<TResultElement>> initialQuery)
    {
        return RunQueryWithBatching(listToBatch, initialQuery, batchSize);
    }

    public static IQueryable<TResultElement> RunQueryWithBatching<TBatchElement, TResultElement>(this IList<TBatchElement> listToBatch, Func<List<TBatchElement>, IQueryable<TResultElement>> initialQuery)
    {
        return RunQueryWithBatching(listToBatch, initialQuery, 0);
    }

    public static IQueryable<TResultElement> RunQueryWithBatching<TBatchElement, TResultElement>(this IList<TBatchElement> listToBatch, Func<List<TBatchElement>, IQueryable<TResultElement>> initialQuery, int batchSize)
    {
        if (listToBatch == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("listToBatch");

        if (initialQuery == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("initialQuery");

        if (batchSize <= 0)
            batchSize = 1000;

        int batchCount = (listToBatch.Count / batchSize) + 1;

        var batchGroup = listToBatch.AsQueryable().Select((elem, index) => new { GroupKey = index % batchCount, BatchElement = elem }); // Enumerable.Range(0, listToBatch.Count).Zip(listToBatch, (first, second) => new { GroupKey = first, BatchElement = second });

        var keysBatchGroup = from obj in batchGroup
                                     group obj by obj.GroupKey into grouped
                                     select grouped;

        var groupedBatches = keysBatchGroup.Select(key => key.Select((group) => group.BatchElement));

        var map = from employeekeysBatchGroup in groupedBatches
                  let batchResult = initialQuery(employeekeysBatchGroup.ToList()).ToList() // force to memory because of stupid translation error in linq2sql
                  from br in batchResult
                  select br;

        return map;
    }
```

usage:

```
using (var context = new SourceDataContext())
{
    // some code
    var myBatchResult = intArray.RunQueryWithBatching(batch => from v1 in context.Table where batch.Contains(v1.IntProperty) select v1, 2000);
    // some other code that makes use of myBatchResult
}
```

then either use result, either expand to list, or whatever you need. Just make sure you don't lose the DataContext reference.